# How can regex look for a specific word in a quote and save the entire quote?

Tags: python, regex

I have read through some documentation and found that (.*?) will look for and store anything in quotes. Is there a way to make it only store quotes that contain a certain word? For example, I am trying to save the quote within this html tag that contains "/pagead/".

```
<a class="tapItem fs-unmask result job_b6963d28b4e50448 sponsoredJob resultWithShelf sponTapItem desktop" data-ci="374815040" data-empn="3407139265172905" data-hide-spinner="true" data-hiring-event="false" data-jk="b6963d28b4e50448" data-mobtk="1fgcm5quto251800" href="/pagead/clk?mo=r&amp;ad=-6NYlbfkN0C4JTuWysBZGWr3ScYyn1q3GP1
```

Comment: What are the boundaries of the quote? A single newline? two newlines? something else?

Comment: `(.*?)` will match a single character or maybe even no characters so maybe you should disregard wherever you read that.

Comment: Are your quotes all single (string) items in a list?

Comment: Try it out at regex101.com or write some code to try it.

Comment: The boundaries are quotation marks: ""

Comment: No they are not all single string items in a list. I updated my question to reflect that.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this regex :

```
"[^"]*\/pagead\/[^"]*"
```

the first and last `"` take what is between quote, `[^"]*` is any characters except `"` and `\/pagead\/` match `/pagead/`

(`/` is a special character that need to be escaped with `\`)

So with this input :

```
<a class="tapItem fs-unmask result job_b6963d28b4e50448 sponsoredJob resultWithShelf sponTapItem desktop" data-ci="374815040" data-empn="3407139265172905" data-hide-spinner="true" data-hiring-event="false" data-jk="b6963d28b4e50448" data-mobtk="1fgcm5quto251800" href="/pagead/clk?mo=r&amp;ad=-6NYlbfkN0C4JTuWysBZGWr3ScYyn1q3GP1"
```

the regex will match :

```
"/pagead/clk?mo=r&amp;ad=-6NYlbfkN0C4JTuWysBZGWr3ScYyn1q3GP1"
```

Comment: What can you use this regex to do? Please explain why+how you have answered the question.

Comment: So would that be implemented like this?
`print(re.findall(r'[^"]*\/pagead\/[^"]*', some_variable)`
or do I have the syntax wrong?

Comment: Yes that's correct. You miss the closing `)` for the `print` statement

Comment: bryton_Petersen are you satisfied by the answer ? If so, can you accept it ? If not, please explain why so i can edit.

Comment: It turns out regex does not work on HTML tags. Ultimately I figured it out by parsing with the BeautifulSoup (bs4) library like this: ```str((link.get('href')))```